# $f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(B))=f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let be $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function. We know that $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$ for any $A\subseteq X$ and so it follows that 
$$
f^{-1}(B)\subseteq f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(B))
$$
for any $B\subseteq Y$; analogously we also know that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$ for any $B\subseteq Y$ and so it follows that
$$
f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f^{-1}(B)
$$
for any $B\subseteq Y$. So from the two inclusions we have $f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(B))=f^{-1}(B)$.

It is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely correct. If you want to make it easier to follow for a reader of the proof, you could add after the first inclusion that we apply it to $A:=f^{-1}[B]$ in particular. And for the second you could add that you're also using that applying $f^{-1}$ to two sets preserves their inclusion relation:

$$B \subseteq B' \subseteq Y\implies f^{-1}[B] \subseteq f^{-1}[B']$$